# Laravel whereDate() in SELECT Statement

Tags: php, sql, laravel, datetime

**Query**

```
<?php

$vrec = DB::table('st_sales_live_bk')->where('brandid', $brandid)
    ->where('branchid', $branchid)
    ->where('module_id', 1)
    ->select(DB::raw('trunc(EODATE)'))
    ->get();

return $vrec;
```

I was using whereDate() in conditions to truncate a DateTime field. Now I want to select a DateTime field (eodate) using `DB::raw`, if possible. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `DB::raw` before your `where` conditions. Your query should look like

```
$vrec=DB::table('st_sales_live_bk')->select(DB::raw('trunc(EODATE)'))
                 ->where('brandid', $brandid)
                 ->where('branchid', $branchid)
                 ->where('module_id', 1)                                
                 ->get();
return $vrec;
```